# Remove the white space around the jpg image button in android studio

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to set an image button. But when I use it on android studio, it has white space   and has thick grey border around it.(its not visible when you view it in photos apk). I've used `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` attribute but it did not work. How can I remove border and white space? (using android studio or other apk)

code for imageboutton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/add_button" />
```

This is how it looks in android studio / on phone :

[image]

And this is how it looks in photos apk(windows) :
[[image]]2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an ImageButton.  It's a button with an image.  The gray border is the button.  If you don't want that and just want a clickable image, use ImageView instead of ImageButton